# Deadlock with a SP

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

Am a new DBA and just got stuck with the below stored procedure that is always involved in deadlock!

The developer asked me to see if anything can be done to improve and how the deadlock occurrence could be avoided. I tried rebuilding indexes, update stats, and recompiled the stored procedure. But still seeing the deadlock.

Any thing the DBA team here would think? this would be really appreciated!

Stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Queue]
    @MaxResults int,
    @ItemType varchar(50),
    @Action varchar(50),
    @ImportanceScore int,
    @FromDB varchar(50),
    @FromDataset varchar(50),
    @FromType varchar(50),
    @ToDB varchar(50),
    @ToDataset varchar(50),
    @ToType varchar(50),
    @LockedBy uniqueidentifier,
    @OnlyUnlocked bit,
    @OrderByImportanceScore bit,
    @from bit
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON 

select top 0 * into #tmpProcessingListItem from [LINK_QUEUE_ITEM]

if (@OrderByImportanceScore = 1)
BEGIN
    insert into #tmpProcessingListItem
    SELECT TOP (@MaxResults) * 
    FROM [LINK_QUEUE_ITEM] with(readpast)
        where 1 = 1 
        and ([ITEM_TYPE] = @ItemType)
        and (isnull(@FromDB, '') = '' or FROM_DB = @FromDB)
        and (isnull(@ToDB, '') = '' or TO_DB = @ToDB) 
        and ([STATUS_ID] > 0)
        and (ISNULL(@Action, '') = '' or [ACTION] = @Action)
        and (ISNULL(@ImportanceScore, 0) = 0 or IMPORTANCE_SCORE = @ImportanceScore)
        and (ISNULL(@FromDataset, '') = '' or FROM_DATASET = @FromDataset)
        and (ISNULL(@FromType, 0) = 0 or FROM_TYPE = @FromType)
        and  (@from =0 or FROM_ID  in (select OBJECT_ID from #TMP_CoreLinking_IDList))
        and (ISNULL(@ToDataset, '') = '' or TO_DATASET = @ToDataset)
        and  (@from =1 or TO_ID  in (select OBJECT_ID from #TMP_CoreLinking_IDList))            
        and (ISNULL(@ToType, 0) = 0 or TO_TYPE = @ToType)
        and (ISNULL(@LockedBy, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' or LOCKED_BY = @LockedBy)
        and (@OnlyUnlocked = 0 or ISNULL(LOCKED_BY, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    order by [IMPORTANCE_SCORE] DESC
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF (@from = 1)
    BEGIN
        insert into #tmpProcessingListItem
        SELECT TOP (@MaxResults) * 
        FROM LINK_QUEUE_ITEM with(index(IX_ITEM_TYPE_ACTIVE), forceseek, readpast)  
            where 1 = 1 
            and ([ITEM_TYPE] = @ItemType)
            and  FROM_ID  in (select OBJECT_ID from #TMP_CoreLinking_IDList)
            and (isnull(@FromDB, '') = '' or FROM_DB = @FromDB)
            and (isnull(@ToDB, '') = '' or TO_DB = @ToDB) 
            and ([STATUS_ID] > 0)
            and (isnull(@Action, '') = '' or [ACTION] = @Action)
            and (isnull(@ImportanceScore, 0) = 0 or IMPORTANCE_SCORE = @ImportanceScore)
            and (isnull(@FromDataset, '') = '' or FROM_DATASET = @FromDataset)
            and (isnull(@FromType, 0) = 0 or FROM_TYPE = @FromType)
            and (isnull(@ToDataset, '') = '' or TO_DATASET = @ToDataset)                
            and (isnull(@ToType, 0) = 0 or TO_TYPE = @ToType)
            and (ISNULL(@LockedBy, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' or LOCKED_BY = @LockedBy)
            and (@OnlyUnlocked = 0 or ISNULL(LOCKED_BY, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        insert into #tmpProcessingListItem
        SELECT TOP (@MaxResults) * 
        FROM LINK_QUEUE_ITEM with(index(IX_ITEM_TYPE_ACTIVE), forceseek, readpast)  
            where 1 = 1 
            and ([ITEM_TYPE] = @ItemType)
            and  TO_ID  in (select OBJECT_ID from #TMP_CoreLinking_IDList)  
            and (isnull(@FromDB, '') = '' or FROM_DB = @FromDB)
            and (isnull(@ToDB, '') = '' or TO_DB = @ToDB) 
            and ([STATUS_ID] > 0)
            and (isnull(@Action, '') = '' or [ACTION] = @Action)
            and (isnull(@ImportanceScore, 0) = 0 or IMPORTANCE_SCORE = @ImportanceScore)
            and (isnull(@FromDataset, '') = '' or FROM_DATASET = @FromDataset)
            and (isnull(@FromType, 0) = 0 or FROM_TYPE = @FromType)
            and (isnull(@ToDataset, '') = '' or TO_DATASET = @ToDataset)
            and (isnull(@ToType, 0) = 0 or TO_TYPE = @ToType)
            and (ISNULL(@LockedBy, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' or LOCKED_BY = @LockedBy)
            and (@OnlyUnlocked = 0 or ISNULL(LOCKED_BY, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    END     
END


SELECT * FROM #tmpProcessingListItem

END

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[sp_Queue]
    TO LinkService;


GO
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could capture and post the deadlock graph xml.  Simply update your question with the captured xml.

Comment: What isolation mode are you running in?

Comment: How often is the procedure run? Maybe adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) to `insert` statements could solve your problem fast.

Comment: How would a recompile option fix a deadlock?  @DenisRubashkin

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response, btw today I was able to add extended events to capture deadlock (got a link to do this) so helpful

Comment: I will try to capture the XML graph i think it can be done with Extended events ?

Comment: Also, the option recompile where do I mention this? and what does this do ?

Comment: @Rishon you didn’t mention the recompile. It was a comment from another user and it’s not applicable for the problem you are facing

Comment: @Aaron, I see queries with optional parameters, such ones usually have problems with performance. I expect clustered index scan on `LINK_QUEUE_ITEM` every time an `insert` statement from the procedure is executed. That can cause different issues and deadlocking as well. So I suggest try to make queries use suitable indexes by informing the query optimizer about variables' runtime values. I should mention though, I have no information on the table indexing and didn't see a deadlock graph that's why it was only comment, not an answer.

Comment: thanks every one, I heard about the execution plan do you think I need to generate one ? which is suitable actual or estimated ?  I am attaching the dead xml file I got through extended event (which is cool tool) . But which is the query that is causing deadlock? I see 2 queries inside it. Please suggest in any way if you guys can! thanks!

Comment: how to attach a file ? wanted to attached the xml file I stored as text!